# Seemingly random lag when moving windows, entering text, or playing games

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, gaming, lag

Patient:

- Ryzen 5 1600
- GTX 1660 Ti
- 16 GB DDR4 3000 MHz RAM
- Win10 2004 on a SATA3 SSD

Issue:

My PC started lagging, for seemingly no reason. Memory usage gets up to 70% tops, CPU usage is around 5-20% depending on the task.

The issue happened before, I think 3 weeks back or so. For the past two weeks everything was peachy, even though I haven't done anything that could've fixed it, but the issues started appearing again, today.

Symptoms:

- Entering text, for example right now, sometimes causes the text to not appear as I type and catch up later, making letters appear near-instantly
- Games are laggy as well, despite running at solid 30-60 FPS without any spikes or dips
- Moving windows around makes the window with a copy of the cursor placed on it move slower than I actually move my mouse. When I let go, I'm free to move my cursor however I want, and the window with the copy of my cursor does its own thing

  - Trying to record it with ShareX produces perfectly normal footage, as if nothing was wrong

Treatment so far:

- `sfc /scannow` found nothing
- `chckdsk` found nothing
- Malwarebytes, ESET – neither found anything
- De-dusting did not help
- Windows' built-in memory diagnostic found nothing
- Already on the newest nVidia drivers

Additional:

- CrystalDiskInfo shows:

  - C (system) – Good (100%)
  - E – Good
  - D – Good
  - G – Good (100%)
  - Details: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjaO2.jpg
- `wmic diskdrive get status` returns `OK` on all drives
- `wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus` returns `FALSE` for each drive in the `PredictFailure` column

Comment: Have you check for SMART errors?

Comment: @DavidPostill Executing `wmic diskdrive get status` returns `OK` on all 4 drives. Also, `wmic /namespace:\\root\wmi path MSStorageDriver_FailurePredictStatus` returns `FALSE` for each drive in the `PredictFailure` column.

Comment: That's **not** a SMART test. [How can I read my hard drive’s SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803)

Comment: I see. I downloaded CrystalDiskInfo, and edited the question with details, as comments cannot be formatted properly,